# Prove that $f(x)$ is continuous for all $p\neq 1$

Tags: calculus, continuity

[image]

First, $f(x)$ is not continuous at $x=1$, because there is no $\delta>0$ such that

$|x-1|<\delta \implies |f(x)-2|<\frac{1}{2}$

So, to prove that it is continuous for all $p\neq 1$, I've tried the following

For $p>1$

$f(x)=2$ for all $x>1$, therefore, for all $\epsilon>0$

$|f(x)-f(p)|<\epsilon \iff |2-2|<\epsilon \iff 0<\epsilon$

Then, I decided to take $\delta = min\left\lbrace p-1,\epsilon \right\rbrace$, because then if $\delta=p-1$, we have

$|x-p|<p-1 \iff 1<x<2p-1 \implies |f(x)-f(p)|<\epsilon$

and if $\delta=\epsilon$ then $1\leq p-\epsilon$ and so

$1\leq p-\epsilon<x<p+\epsilon \implies |f(x)-f(p)|<\epsilon$

The I would do similarly for $p<1$.

Is it valid ?

Answer (score 2):

So your problem is to pick such $\delta$ that $|x-p| < \delta$ would ensure that $x>1$. In that case, taking $\delta=p-1$ will work for any $\epsilon$. Which means that your approach will also work.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Consider the case $x>1$, then $f(x)=2$. Consider the case $x<1$, then $f(x)=1$. Prove that these functions are continuous and you would be done.